# What is appropriate distance between signatures?

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, soft-question, stochastic-differential-equations, rough-path-theory

This question is related to rough path theory. A link to wikipedia is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rough_path

I can understand to an extent how to calculate signatures given a path. I am interested to know what kind of distance measure possible between two signatures arises from two different paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three wooly suggestions for definitions of distance. Just definitions, not necessarily practical distances to calculate for given data. I assume your two paths *X* and *Y* have the same number of dimensions.

1. If you have the signatures truncated to a fixed level *m*, you can concatenate the step-*m* signature of *X* with the step-*m* signature of (*Y* backwards) to get a step-*m* signature *Z*. Then define the distance as the length of the unique shortest Lipschitz path whose step-*m* signature is *Z*. This is called the *Carnot-Caratheodory distance* on  page 10 of the book "Multidimensional Stochastic Processes as Rough Paths: Theory and Applications" by Friz and Victoir.
2. If the signatures are truncated to level *m*, they just live in a finite dimensional vector space. You can pick any norm you like on that space and its value on the difference of the signatures will be a distance. In particular, you could take the homogenous norm, the maximum over *i* of (the $\ell_i$ norm of level $i$), which gives you an equivalent topology to the previous idea, as explained on page 12 of the same book.
3. Suppose you had the whole of each path, and not just its signature. Then you could take the signature of any sub-interval of the path. If, further, the paths were defined on the *same* interval, then you could pick a *p* and take the *p*-variation metric in the rough path sense as explained on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rough_path#Definition_of_a_rough_path). This distance would change if you reparametrised one of the paths. Now, you can find a canonical path which agrees with each of your signatures (the tree reduced one if you have the full signature, or the shortest one if they are truncated at level *m*). If you can find a canonical parametrisation (easy in the truncated case - use length, but I don't know how to do this if you specify the whole signature), and sort out scaling the parametrisation to make both be over the same interval, then you can use this metric.

Comment: If I am not asking two much, may I request a simple numerical example of Carnot-Caratheodory distance for signature only level 3 for a 2 D path of only 3 points? Should l I ask a separate question instead?

Comment: I think finding the shortest path which has a given signature truncated to level 3 or above is an open problem. I could be wrong, and someone might discover the answer, so I guess a mathoverflow question could be useful. For level 2, the answer is an arc (I think this goes back to Brockett and Dai in https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4615-3176-0_1), which can be worked out by hand easily.

Comment: Does it make sense  to consider a two dimensional path where each dimension may represent different  things like one dimension may represent time and other frequency. Can we treat the signature of such path as a tool for comparison like a feature?

Comment: Yes. Are you thinking here about using signatures as representations of path data in machine learning(which is quite different from this question). If so, you may need to pay attention to scaling, because the signature elements will each scale differently. Strategies for that might be worth another question.

Comment: May I ask what the scaling means? Is it the contribution of each dimension to the signature? For example the variable 'sig' in your matlab code the first element has two component, the difference between first and second component; for the second element (4 component) the difference between first two components and 3rd and 4th component, for third element difference between 1 to 4th component and 5th to 8th component?

Comment: Best to ask a new question or contact me another way, this is far away from this question/answer topic. Simplest thing is to imagine a change of units in one dimension- with time vs frequency you'd expect this to leave your machine learning pipeline unaffected, noting that it affects signature elements differently.